# hbase rowkey must be the same length?

Tags: hbase

from https://hbase.apache.org,I know some principles about hbase rowkey design.

for example: the length as shorter as better and something else.

I have a question: hbase rowkey must be the same length or not?

who knows!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

HBase stores data in key alphabetical order, the length of the key does not matter.

Comment: thank you for you answer.if the length of rowkey is not same,Does it affect query efficiency?

Comment: @kevin you will not notice any performance impact if your keys have reasonable size, though key is a part of the data you request